# MySQL Start Service

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, remote-access, rdp, windows-service

Is it possible to, remotely using MySQL, to start a service on the server, or to run any file? What about FTP, can you tell it to run a file? I ask because a developer I work with has killed apache, and locked us out of RDP.

Comment: RDP not working because apache stopped? "run any file"? Sounds like you're looking to hack a solution to a problem you don't really understand.

Comment: No, I understand the problem. The developer stopped apache, and I don't know what he did to cause RDP to stop working, I'm just wondering if It's possible to use MySQL or FTP to find out what's going on.

Comment: No, it is not possible (without exploiting security vulnerabilities) to start stuff remotely with neither FTP nor MySQL. Perhaps you should talk with the developer, and ask him/her to bring up apache again?

Comment: Heh, that's the issue, he doesn't have access either. He will have to go to the server I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the session 0 via:

```
mstsc /v:serverip /f -console
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your FTP service able to write to C:\Windows\Tasks? Make a .job file to issue a "net start" and throw it in there. Seems worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the administrative share of the machine, then you should be able to connect to the services manager remotely.

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.  Then right-click on "Services (Local)" in the left-hand pane, and select "Connect to another computer..."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but all ports are closed but FTP, and MySql. Not sure why RDP won't respond.

Comment: I'm afraid I think you're out of luck.  If your FTP or MySQL servers did allow arbitrary execution of code that would be very scary indeed (from a security point of view).  In MSSQL you have master..xp_cmdshell which allows execution of external programs, but there isn't anything like this in mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [PsExec tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

This should allow you to remote in and enable Services.
`Psexec net start <service name>`

Comment: And what port does it use? I'd guess not FTP or MySQL, it didn't work.

Comment: For using PSexec on the remote machine, the remote machine should have opened port 445 TCP (SMB).

Comment: Yeah I don't have that.